# XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString() not converting to UTF-8

Tags: xml, utf-8, xmlwriter

I have the following code to create an XML file. Why is it not doing a UTF-8 conversion on the string passed in?

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestXmlWriter
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly Encoding utf8NoBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stream stream = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\test.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, utf8NoBOM);
            xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("bear");
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("version", "CONSULTOR_TÉCNICO");

            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            xmlWriter.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><bear version="CONSULTOR_TÉCNICO" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that the encoding of the string literal in your C# source code is correct? I'm generally very reluctant to use non-ASCII characters in source code - it can easily get mangled by things like source code repositories.

Comment: @MichaelKay - The string written is from a variable, not a literal C# string and we get what we get (it's saving off metadata). But if you look at the example I posted - it is a character > 255 and it's writing it literally to the output.